# Get Values of Multidimensional array inside of another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi i am having this structure:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
            'mysql' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname' => 'database'
                ),
            'session' => array(
                    'session_name' => 'user'
                ),
            'remember' => array(
                    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
                    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
                ),
            'folder' => array(
                    'root' => 'backend',
                    'header' => 'head',
                    'views' => 'views'
                ),
            'database' => array(
                    'names' => 'utf8mb4',
                    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
                    'driver' => 'pdo'
                ),
            'url' => array(
                'base_url' => 'http://www.example.com/backend/',
                'document_root' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/backend"
                ),
            'languages' => array(
                    'english' => 'en',
                    'german' => 'de',
                    'greek' => 'gr'
                ),
            'headers' => array(
                    '404' => 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found',
                    '401' => 'HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized',
                    '500' => 'HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error',
                    '403' => 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden'
                ),
            'title' => array(
                    'login' => 'Admin Dashboard',
                    'register' => 'Admin Dashboard | User Registration',
                )
        );
```

and i want in the url/base_url to be like this

```
'base_url' => 'http://www.example.com/'.$GLOBALS['config']['folder']['root'].'/'
```

so if i change folder i only have to change the name in only place, but i get a Syntax error like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: config in C:\xampp-php56\htdocs\backend\core\init.php on line 31
```

Is possible what i am trying to do? and if possible how?

Comment: You can't reference an array's index within its own array definition

Comment: any idea how can i reference to the folder array within this url array?

Comment: Just set it after you've defined the array.

Comment: @BRG see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access another array index while you're still defining the array. Your statement defining the array hasn't completed yet, the array isn't available for access until the initial statement is finished.

You need to setup your array as much as you can first, and then go back and add the array elements that reference other array indexes.

So first just create your big array like you're doing, without the base_url.

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    ...
);
```

Now go back and add the url/base_url, you can now access the array index of `config`.

```
$GLOBALS['config']['url']['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/'.$GLOBALS['config']['folder']['root'].'/';
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/M7itf

Comment: @BRG I don't think you understand. You _can't access an array index while you're in the middle of defining the array_. You can't do what you're trying to do. I'm showing you the proper way to accomplish this, even if it's not what you wanted.

Comment: @BRG see the example link I just included

Answer (score 1):

Missed dot
'base_url' => 'http://www.example.com/'**.**$GLOBALS['config']['folder']['root'].'/'

Comment: and now it says undefined index config...i guess it cannot see that the folder is named config